# Sufficient condition on $f$ to make $g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \max(y-x, 0)f(y)dy$ strictly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $Y$ be a random variable and $$g(x) = \mathrm{E}[\text{max}(Y-x, 0)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{max}(y-x, 0)f(y)dy$$ I know that $g$ is convex since for any fixed $y$, $\text{max}(y-x, 0)$ is convex and $f(y) \geq 0$.

My question is that what is the most general condition on $f$ (if any), such that $g$ becomes strictly convex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take.

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{max}(y-x, 0)f(y)dy\\
&=\int_{x}^{\infty} (y-x)f(y)dy\\
&=\int_{x}^{\infty} yf(y)dy
-x\int_{x}^{\infty} f(y)dy\\
\end{array}
$

Differentiating,
$g'(x)
=-xf(x)
-(x(-f(x)+\int_{x}^{\infty} f(y)dy)
=-\int_{x}^{\infty} f(y)dy
$.

Differentiating again,
$g''(x)
=-(-f(x))
=f(x)
$.

So,
if $f(x) > 0$,
then
$g(x)$
is strictly convex.

Comment: This implies that $g''(x) = -f(x) \leq 0$. It seems that this result must not be true, since it proves that $g$ is not even convex.

Comment: Or maybe my primary justification that $g$ is convex is not true.

Comment: It turns out that $g''(x) = f(x)$, as my corrected answer shows.